# Data multiplies on mysql query

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(
    id_employee INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    Last_name VARCHAR(20),
    Gender VARCHAR(1),
    Area INT     

 );
```

Created a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE Area(
    id_area INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Area_name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

I want that the column Area in Employee transform in a foreign key of the column id_area from the table Area, so i alter the table.

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD FOREIGN KEY(Area)
REFERENCES Area(id_area)
ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

When i use DESC on the employee table it seems ok, the Area column is now MUL.

Now i enter the data in table Area:

```
INSERT INTO Area VALUES(1, 'Grphic Design');
INSERT INTO Area VALUES(2, '3D Design');
INSERT INTO Area VALUES (3,'Software');
INSERT INTO Area VALUES(4, 'Administration');
```

Now i enter my first value in Employee:

```
INSERT INTO Empleados VALUES (109,'Charles', 
'Cook','M',1);
```

And finally i use this query to see how the table is going, if the columns are related:

```
SELECT Name, Employee.Area, Area.id_area
FROM Employee, Area;
```

And i got this result:

```
Name    | Area | id_area
Charles |   1  |    1
Charles |   1  |    2
Charles |   1  |    3
Charles |   1  |    4
```

Ok, what did i do wrong and why my code is trash? with that query in mind, shouldnt all the results be Charles 1, id_area 1? and only one result? i got four everytime, if i add another person, the results of this query multiply adding another 1234 bullcrap.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your implicit `JOIN` in your query:

```
SELECT Name, Employee.Area, Area.id_area
FROM Employee, Area;
```

The `,` symbol is equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`, and since you have no condition on the `JOIN` it becomes a `CROSS JOIN`, joining every row of `Employee` to every row of `Area`. Even though `Employee.Area` is a foreign key to `Area.id_area` it doesn't force the tables to be joined on that key, you need to specify it explicitly as a `JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT Name, Employee.Area, Area.id_area
FROM Employee
JOIN Area ON Employee.Area = Area.id_area
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i wasted too much time on this problem, now i can rest.